# comparing all elements of two big files

Tags: c, perl

How to compare All elements of a file with All elements of another file using C or Perl for much larger data? File 1 contains 100,000 such numbers and file 2 contains 500,000 elements.

I used foreach within a foreach with spliting each and every element in arrays. It worked perfectly in perl but the time consumed to check and print every occurrence of elements of just a single column from File2 in file1 was 40 minutes.  There are 28 such columns.

Is there any way to reduce the time or using another language like C?

#### File 1:

```
0.1
0.11
0.12
0.13
0.14
0.15
0.16
0.17
0.18
0.19
0.2
```

#### File 2:

```
0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 0.1 0.11    0.12    0.13    0.14    0.15    0.16    0.17    0.18    0.19    0.2 0.21    0.22    0.23    0.24    0.25    0.26    0.27    0.28
1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9 1.1 1.11    1.12    1.13    1.14    1.15    1.16    1.17    1.18    1.19    1.2 1.21    1.22    1.23    1.24    1.25    1.26    1.27    1.28
```

### EDIT:

### Expected output:

If element in file 2, matched print 'column number' if not print '0'.

```
1  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0   
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Here is the code I am using. Note: it checks File2 columnwise in File 1 and prints the *Column Number* if *true* and '0' if *false*.  It will print output for every column in 28 different files.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl-w
chomp($file = "File1.txt");
open(FH, $file);
@k_org = <FH>;
chomp($hspfile = 'file2.txt');
open(FH1, $hspfile);
@hsporg = <FH1>;
for $z (1 .. 28) {
  open(OUT, ">$z.txt");
  foreach (@hsporg) {
    $i = 0;
    @h_org = split('\t', $_);
    chomp ($h_org[0]);
    foreach(@k_org) {
      @orginfo = split('\t', $_);
      chomp($orginfo[0]);
      if($h_org[0] eq $orginfo[0]) {
        print OUT "$z\n";
        $i = 1;
        goto LABEL;
      } elsif ($h_org[0] ne $orginfo[0]) {
        if($h_org[0]=~/(\w+\s\w+)\s/) {
          if($orginfo[0] eq $1) {
            print  OUT "0";
            $i = 1;
            goto LABEL;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if ($i == 0) {
      print OUT "0";
    }
    LABEL: 
  }
}
close FH;
close FH1;
close OUT;
```

Comment: If I said there was not way to do this in any language besides Perl, would you believe it? *Of course not.* Of course you can do it in C. If the language you're using confines the logic core and efficiencies you need to do it well and exhibit reasonable asymptotic behavior, considering a different language is warranted, but you better *know* you're conclusion of current language limitation is sound. I'm no Perl engineer, but there are *many* that are very good with that language. Consider showing them *what you've done so far* and seeing if they can help make the code more efficient.

Comment: "every occurance of a single column from File2 in file1" -- what does this mean? What does your program actually do? Most likely you need to store one file or the other in a data structure with a fast way to check for membership (which in the case of Perl could be a hash), but it's difficult to say exactly what, because the description is so vague.

Comment: @WhozCraig He was probably thinking that if perl isn't fast enough, then C might be faster. The performance problem is not due to the use of perl, of course, but due to the O(n*m) algorithm.

Comment: @steve : In my actual file2 there are 70,000 rows and 28 columns. I just gave an estimate that it took 40 minutes to check occurances of all 70,000 elemens in column 1 of file2. For all elements of all 28 columns the time would be huge.

Comment: @klas : I guess split in perl actually calls pp.c which is basically written in C.

Comment: @Nari2: The problem with your current double `foreach` solution is not the amount of data and it is not the cost of calling `split`, the problem is the cost of looking up a single value in file1. If you load file1 into a map the cost will fall from O(n) to O(log n).

Comment: the question is not clear, but it is a good question. It is not a problem with perl or C, it is a problem of which algorithm is the best to accomplished the task, and which language already support this algorithm.

Comment: To sum it up: *Please* post your existing code and a better description of your requirements, especially your expected output or resulting data structure. It is then easy for us to see if your existing code is very inefficient, and can help you to optimize. Porting to C may or may not result in a significant speedup for this kind of task. **Until you update your post, this isn't a real question:** it can't be answered in the current form.

Answer (score 5):

If you [`sort(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) the files you can then check it in a single pass. Should not take more than a couple of seconds (including the sort).

Another way is to load all values from file1 into a hash. It's a bit more memory-consuming, especially if file1 is large, but should be fast (again, no more than a couple of seconds).

I would choose perl over C for such a job, and I'm more proficient in C than in perl. It's much faster to code in perl for this kind of job, less error-prone and runs fast enough.

Comment: I am on windows 8. My actual files are huge. It's impossible in few seconds.

Comment: My time estimates are based on the 100,000 and 500,000 element file sizes you mentioned in your question. If you want to use `sort(1)` on windows you can install cygwin. Otherwise just go with the second option (provided your system has enough memory put file1 in a map).

Comment: @Nari2, 100 000 and 500 000 are not "huge". In fact, they're minuscule

Comment: @Nari2 Its nowhere close to huge. As I said, let these very kind folk that know Perl like it was their auto-biography have a chance at your Perl code before deciding it is out. Good Perl runtimes are *very* impressive when used efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

This script runs a test case. Note that your expected output is objectively wrong: In file 2, line 1, column 20, the value `0.2` exists.

```
#!perl

use 5.010; # just for `say`
use strict; use warnings;
use Test::More;

# define input files + expected outcome
my $file_1_contents = <<'_FILE1_';
0.1
0.11
0.12
0.13
0.14
0.15
0.16
0.17
0.18
0.19
0.2
_FILE1_

my $file_2_contents = <<'_FILE2_';
0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 0.1 0.11 0.12 0.13 0.14 0.15 0.16 0.17 0.18 0.19 0.2 0.21 0.22 0.23 0.24 0.25 0.26 0.27 0.28
1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9 1.1 1.11 1.12 1.13 1.14 1.15 1.16 1.17 1.18 1.19 1.2 1.21 1.22 1.23 1.24 1.25 1.26 1.27 1.28
_FILE2_

my $expected_output = <<'_OUTPUT_';
1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
_OUTPUT_

# open the filehandles
open my $file1, "<", \$file_1_contents or die "$!";
open my $file2, "<", \$file_2_contents or die "$!";
open my $expected, "<", \$expected_output or die "$!";

my %file1 = map { chomp; 0+$_ => undef } <$file1>;

while (<$file2>) {
    chomp;
    my @vals = split;
    # If value exists in file1, print the col number.
    my $line = join " " => map { exists $file1{0+$vals[$_]} ? $_+1 : 0 } 0 .. $#vals;
    chomp(my $expected_line = <$expected>);
    is $line, $expected_line;
}
done_testing;
```

To print the exact same output to 28 files, you would remove the testing code, and rather

```
say {$_} $line for @filehandles;
```

instead.

## Old answer

Your existing code is simply quite inefficient and unidiomatic. Let me help you fix that.

First, start *all* your Perl scripts with `use strict; use warnings;`, and if you have a modern perl (v10 or later), you could do `use 5.010;` (or whatever your version is) to activate additional features.

The `chomp` call takes a variable and removes the current value of `$/` (usually a newline) from the end of the string. This is important because the readline operator doesn't do that for us. It is not good for declaring a constant variable. Rather, do

```
my $file   = "File1.txt"; 
my $hspfle = "File2.txt";
```

The `use strict` forces you to declare your variables properly, you can do so with `my`.

To open a file, you should use the following idiom:

```
open my $fh, "<", $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
```

Instead of `or die ...` you can `use autodie` at the top of your script.

This will abort the script if you can't open the file, tell you the reason (`$!`), and specifies an explicit open mode (here: `<` = read). This avoids bugs with special characters in filenames.

Lexical filehandles (in `my` variables, as contrasted to bareword filehandles) have proper scope, and close themselves. There are various other reasons why you should use them.

The `split` function takes a regex, not a string as first argument. If you inspect your program closely, you will see that you `split` each element in `@hsporg` 28 times, and each element in `@k_org` 28 × @hsporg times. This is extremely slow, and unneccessary, as we can do that beforehand.

If a condition is false, you don't need to explicitely test for the falseness again in

```
if ($h_org[0] eq $orginfo[0]) {
  ...;
} elsif ($h_org[0] ne $orginfo[0]) {
  ...;
}
```

as `$a ne $b` is exactly equivalent to `not $a eq $b`.

It is quite unidiomatic in Perl to use a `goto`, and jumping to a label somewhere isn't especially fast either. Labels are mainly used for loop control:

```
# random example
LOOP: for my $i (1 .. 10) {
  for my $j (1 .. 5) {
    next      if     $i == $j; # start next iteration of current loop
    next LOOP if 2 * $i == $j; # start next iteration of labeled loop
    last LOOP if $i + $j == 13;# like `break` in C
  }
```

The `redo` loop control verb is similar to `next`, but doesn't recheck the loop condition, if there is one.

Because of these loop control facilities, and the ability to break out of any enclosing loop, maintaining flags or elaborate gotos is often quite unneccessary.

---

Here is a cleaned-up version of your script, without fixing too much of the actual algorithm:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use autodie; # automatic error messages

my ($file, $hspfile) = ("File1.txt", "file2.txt");
open my $fh1, "<", $file;
open my $fh2, "<", $hspfile;

my @k_org  = <$fh1>;
my @hsporg = <$fh2>;

# Presplit the contents of the arrays:
for my $arr (\@k_org, \@hsporg) {
  for (@$arr) {
    chomp;
    $_ = [ split /\t/ ]; # put an *anonymous arrayref* into each slot
  }
}

my $output_files = 28;

for my $z (1 .. $output_files) {
  open my $out, ">", "$z.txt";

  H_ORG:
  for my $h_org (@hsporg) {
    my $i = 0;

    ORGINFO:
    for my $orginfo (@k_org) {
      # elements in array references are accessed like $arrayref->[$i]
      if($h_org->[0] eq $orginfo->[0]) {
        print $out "$z\n";
        $i = 1;
        last ORGINFO; # break out of this loop
      } elsif($h_org->[0] =~ /(\w+\s\w+)\s/ and $orginfo->[0] eq $1) {
        print $out "0";
        $i = 1;
        last ORGINFO;
      }
    }
    print $out "0" if not $i;
  }
}

# filehandles are closed automatically.
```

Now we can optimize further: In each line, you only ever use the first element. This means we don't have to store the rest:

```
...;
  for (@$arr) {
    chomp;
    $_ = (split /\t/, $_, 2)[0]; # save just the first element
  }
...;
    ORGINFO:
    for my $orginfo (@k_org) {
      # elements in array references are accessed like $arrayref->[$i]
      if($h_org eq $orginfo) {
        ...;
      } elsif($h_org =~ /(\w+\s\w+)\s/ and $orginfo eq $1) {
        ...;
      }
    }
```

Also, acessing scalars is a bit faster than accessing array elements.

The third arg to `split` limits the number of resulting fragments. Because we are only interested in the first field, we don't have to split the rest too.

Next on, we `last` out of the `ORGINFO` loop, then check a flag. This is unneccessary: We can jump directly to the next iteration of the `H_ORG` loop instead of setting the flag. If we drop out naturally out of the `ORGINFO` loop, the flag is guaranteed to not be set, so we can execute the `print` anyway:

```
  H_ORG:
  for my $h_org (@hsporg) {
    for my $orginfo (@k_org) {
      if($h_org eq $orginfo) {
        print $out "$z\n";
        next H_ORG;
      } elsif($h_org =~ /(\w+\s\w+)\s/ and $orginfo eq $1) {
        print $out "0";
        next H_ORG;
      }
    }
    print $out "0";
  }
```

Then, you compare the *same* data 28 times to print it to different files. Better: Define two subs `print_index` and `print_zero`. Inside these, you loop over the output filehandles:

```
# make this initialization *before* you use the subs!
my @filehandles = map {open my $fh, ">", "$_.txt"; $fh} 1 .. $output_files;

...; # the H_ORG loop

sub print_index {
  for my $i (0 .. $#filehandles) {
    print {$filehandles[$i]} $i+1, "\n";
  }
}
sub print_zero {
  print {$_} 0 for @filehandles;
}
```

Then:

```
  # no enclosing $z loop!
  H_ORG:
  for my $h_org (@hsporg) {
    for my $orginfo (@k_org) {
      if($h_org eq $orginfo) {
        print_index()
        next H_ORG;
      } elsif($h_org =~ /(\w+\s\w+)\s/ and $orginfo eq $1) {
        print_zero();
        next H_ORG;
      }
    }
    print_zero();
  }
```

This avoids checking data you already know doesn't match.

Comment: At the moment, this just critizises your code and discusses how to speed it up. However, your code and the description of your algorithm don't seem to match. I'll come back later to write something on that.

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation. Code that you provided first, took 45 mins for one file to print; which is 5 mins more than that of my initial code.

Comment: @Nari2 Ok, that is unfortunate. I have a hard time reasoning about your code. Could you update your question to include the *expected output* for your given files, so that I can test and benchmark my ideas? I have some more ideas how to solve your problem faster, but I need a complete test case for that. (For the given input, your script just writes two zero to each file)

Comment: AMON see my expected output.

Comment: @Nari2 I updated with a newer solution. It runs your (corrected) test case, but you'll have to implement the mutliple output files yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In C you could try using "qsort" and "bsearch" functions

First you need to load your files into an array.

Than you should execute a qsort() (unless you are sure the elements have an order). And use the bsearch() to execute a binary search into your array.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/bsearch

This will be much more faster than check all elements one by one.

*You could try to implement a binary search in perl if it do not exist already, it is a simple algorithm.*